# getTweets in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm a JavaScript newbie who was first introduced to JavaScript by jQuery. I'm trying to switch over some of the small things I've written in jQuery to JavaScript as a way of learning. I was wondering how I could make my code cleaner and if there were any bad habits which I am guilty of doing.

```
function getTweets(user) {

    //Adds a little animation to the body when function is executed
    $('.container').html('<div class="loading"></div>');
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0]; 
    container.innerHTML = "<div class='loading'></div>";

    $.getJSON("https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=" + user + "&callback=?&count=50", function(data) {

        var date = {
            Sun : 'Sunday, ',
            Sat : 'Saturday, ',
            Mon : 'Monday, ',
            Tue : 'Tuesday, ',
            Wed : 'Wednesday, ',
            Fri : 'Friday, ',
            Thu : 'Thursday, ',
        };
        // Creates a box and puts JSON data into it.
        for ( var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
            // Makes the dates readable and links work.
            data[i].text = data[i].text.replace(/(http[s]*:\/\/[\w/\.]+)/, '<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>')
            day = date[ data[i].created_at.match(/\w+/)[0] ];
            data[i].created_at = data[i].created_at.replace(/(\+\d+)/g, '').replace(/\w+/, day);

            var art = document.createElement('article');

            art.innerHTML = "<h3>" + data[i].user.name + "</h3><span class='date'>" + data[i].created_at + "</span><p>" + data[i].text + "</p>";
            container.appendChild(art);

        };
        //Everything after this is to dynamically create a Pinterest type layout
        var width = Math.floor( ( $(window).width() - 200 )/225),
            col = [],
            small = 0,
            articleArray = document.getElementsByTagName('article');

        while ( col.length < width ) {
            col.push(0)
        };


        for (var o = 0; o < articleArray.length; o++) {

            articleArray[o].style.top = col[small] + "px";
            articleArray[o].style.left = small*225 + "px";

            col[small] += articleArray[o].clientHeight + 5;

            for ( var j = 0; j < width; j++ ) { 

                if (col[j] < col[small]) {
                    small = j
                }

            };
        };

        container.style.height = col[small] + 'px';
        container.style.width = col.length * 225 - 5 + 'px';

        $('.container .loading').fadeOut();
        $('article').fadeIn();

    });

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First step to making the code look good is proper indentation. [JSBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) can do that for you.
- Next is consistency. If you use jQuery, you can go all-out with jQuery to make it as neat and uniform. Of course, you can do vanilla JS if you want to for optimization.
- Then remove duplicate code or code that does the same thing over and over again.
- Watch out for missed `var`s. This can make variables to globals which isn't good.
- When declaring, follow this order:

  - variables
  - functions
  - "prep code" like initializers, code to fill arrays, fetching values etc.
  - actual operation of the function

The rest are commented so keep a sharp eye. Can't really debug the code but the idea of what to do are there:

```
function getTweets(user) {

    //cache an object if it's to be used more than once
    var container = $('.container').html('<div class="loading"></div>'),

        //put the url up here so it does not clutter the getJSON below
        //i prefer using single quotes than double quotes for a cleaner look
        url = 'https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=' + user + '&callback=?&count=50';

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

        //it's logical to only put things where they are needed
        //in this case, the following variables are only needed
        //when the callback completes
        var date = {
            Sun: 'Sunday, ',
            Sat: 'Saturday, ',
            Mon: 'Monday, ',
            Tue: 'Tuesday, ',
            Wed: 'Wednesday, ',
            Fri: 'Friday, ',
            Thu: 'Thursday, '
        },
            width = Math.floor(($(window).width() - 200) / 225),
            col = [],
            small = 0,
            articleArray = $('article');

        //prep codes after vars
        while(col.length < width) {
            col.push(0)
        };

        //consistency and ease, use jQuery instead.
        $.each(data, function (i, value) {
            //watch out for missed "vars"
            var day = date[value.created_at.match(/\w+/)[0]],
                //shorthand notation for creating a variable, appending it to the container directly
                //we can hand it over to a reference to do more on it
                art = $('<article>').appendTo(container);
            value.text = value.text.replace(/(http[s]*:\/\/[\w/\.]+)/, '<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>')
            value.created_at = value.created_at.replace(/(\+\d+)/g, '').replace(/\w+/, day);
            art.html('<h3>' + value.user.name + '</h3><span class="date">' + value.created_at + '</span><p>' + value.text + '</p>');
        });


        container.css({
            width : col.length * 225 - 5,
            height : col[small]
        })

        //using the built in each to loop through DOM
        articleArray.each(function (i, article) {
            $(article).css({
                'top': col[small],
                'left': small * 225
            });
            col[small] += article.clientHeight + 5;
            for(var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                if(col[j] < col[small]) {
                    small = j
                }
            }
        }).fadeIn(); //chain whenever necessary

        //using context to limit the scope of the selector search
        $('.loading', container).fadeOut();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small note:

1. `225` should be constant, the code uses it three times. ([Unnamed numerical constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants) on Wikipedia)
2. Comments often could be function names and the commented code could be extracted out to these functions. For example:

   - `// Creates a box and puts JSON data into it.`: `createBoxWithFilledData(...)`,
   - `// Makes the dates readable and links work.`: `makeDatesReadable(...)`, `fixLinks(...)`,
   - `// Everything after this is to dynamically create a Pinterest type layout`: `createLayout(...)`.

   Reference:

   - *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *Bad Comments, p67*: *Don’t Use a Comment When You Can Use a Function or a Variable*.
   - *Refactoring* by *Martin Fowler*, *Chapter 3. Bad Smells in Code*, *Long Method*
3. In the `for` loop I'd create a local variable for `data[i]`. I'd make the code readable and shorter.